# I coded a snake game, and want to add the WASD keys, as well as keep the arrow keys as controls

Tags: python

here is the arrow key controls code:

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]
```

how can I add the WASD keys as controls as well?
I can't seem to find anything online to help me, and I'm running out of things to say cuz the site won't let me post because I posted a lot of code......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is stopping you from using an "or" operator?

```
if Ekeys[pygame.K_LEFT] or EKeys[pygame.K_a]:
```